# CSS/jQ/jS - Prev/Next buttons won't stack on img cycler

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slideshow, cycle

I'm trying to make a image cycler with prev/next navigation. I got it running, but the navigation buttons won't appear on the img. I used `<li> a:` and a background with text indent -9999px and set the z-index higher than the img.

CSS

```
div#slideshow {
  width: 1920px; height: 816px;
  overflow: scroll; 
  position: relative; z-index: 5;}

div#slideshow ul#navigation {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative; top: 375px; z-index: 15;}

div#slideshow ul#navigation li#prev {
    float: left;}

div#slideshow ul#navigation li#next {
    float: right;}

div#slideshow ul#navigation li a {
    display: block; width: 65px; height: 66px; text-indent: -9999px;}
div#slideshow ul#navigation li#prev a {
    background: url(http://www.nobodyfilm.org/images/Arrow-Left.jpg);}
div#slideshow ul#navigation li#next a {
    background: url(http://www.nobodyfilm.org/images/Arrow-Right.jpg);}

div#slideshow ul#slides {
    list-style: none;}
```

jQ

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#slideshow").css("overflow", "hidden");

$("ul#slides").cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    pause: 1,
    prev: '#prev',
    next: '#next'
});

$("#slideshow").hover(function() {
    $("ul#navigationv").fadeIn();
    },
        function() {
    $("ul#navigation").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="slideshow">
    <ul id="navigation">
      <li id="prev"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
      <li id="next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul id="slides">
      <li><img src="http://nobodyfilm.org/images/Mr.-Nobody-Train-Station.jpg" alt="Pic1" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://nobodyfilm.org/images/Mr.-Nobody-Overview-and-Production.jpg" alt="Pic2" /></li>
      <li><img src="http://nobodyfilm.org/images/Mr.-Nobody-Themes-And-Philosophy.jpg" alt="Pic3" /></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://nobodyfilm.org/slideshow.html

**EDIT** : anyone know what's the reason for navigation elements disappearing when moving mouse off the container element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They aren't showing cause you have them hidden: Change the following:

```
div#slideshow ul#navigation {
  display: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative; top: 375px; z-index: 15;
}
```

to this:

```
div#slideshow ul#navigation {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative; top: 375px; z-index: 15;
}
```

Notice I have used `display:block;` instead of `display:none;`

Comment: hey, thanks it worked. Got another problem now tho. The navigation dissapears when I move my mouse off the element. Got to be something with jQ. I'll try to figure it out. I updated the site if anyone got any clue (http://nobodyfilm.org/slideshow.html)

Comment: It seems that the jquery code that shows the buttons upon hovering is causing the problem. I removed it on a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FrqaZ/) and it works fine now: